# How to use existing cumulocity widget in custom widget

Tags: cumulocity

I created a custom widget using angular 10, Now I wanted to add a datapoint list in the configuration(edit) and access it

I am using `c8y-data-point-list` directive but my angular application not able to find this selector/associated component.

so my first question is how to use the existing angularJs component in angular? how to import it?
is it possible?

I also want to use more widget in a custom widget from ng1-module, how to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

c8y-data-point-list is not in the official list of cumulocity components, so it's not possible to use it.
Also the highest version of angular would be the 8th, as they currently only support it and still use angularJS components.